# client-go for Kubernetes run apply commands

Tags: go, kubernetes

How can I run kubectl apply commands from go via client-go?
e.g.:
I'm having a file called crds.yaml and I want to run it via client-go

I can't find any examples about how to do so can someone please help?

Answer (score 2):

You need to decode your .yaml file

[Here](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/issues/216) it's the complete answer (with code example)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up having this type of call based on what is on the link you provided

```
    yamlFile, err := ioutil.ReadFile("custom.yaml")
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("yamlFile.Get err   #%v ", err)
    }

    var ctx context.Context
    var c client.Client
    var actionFn ForEachObjectInYAMLActionFunc

    err = ForEachObjectInYAML(ctx, c, yamlFile, "default", actionFn)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
```

But it is failing with

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x10ac5cc]

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.ForEachObjectInYAML({0x0, 0x0}, {0x0, 0x0}, {0xc000880000?, 0xc0000021a0?, 0x200000003?}, {0x12bf20f, 0x7}, 0x0)
       apply.go:125 +0x12c
main.main()
       apply.go:34 +0xc5
exit status 2
```

And there is:

```
if err := actionFn(ctx, c, obj); err != nil {
    return err
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?